# How to address days relatively?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to address days addressed relatively of today, for example "today minus 3 days". Is there any way to code this relation?

I'd like to use it in Boolean conditions.

For (just a logic) example:

```
ThisIsThatVeryDay = Today - 3
Event = SomethingSomething and ThisIsThatVeryDay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [timenow](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_timenow) and [time_tradingday](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_time_tradingday) variables to determine if the bar on which the script is currently calculating on was a certain number of days ago.

```js
//@version=5
indicator("relativeDays", overlay = true)

var int MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY = 86400000

int daysSince1970RelativeToNow = math.floor(timenow / MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY)
int daysSince1970RelativeToBar = math.floor(time_tradingday / MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY)

wasBarFormedXDaysAgo(int daysAgo) =>
    daysSince1970RelativeToNow - daysSince1970RelativeToBar == daysAgo

// Use green background for bars that were formed 3 days ago
bgcolor(wasBarFormedXDaysAgo(3) ? color.new(color.green, 75) : na)

// Debug
plot(timenow, "timenow", display = display.data_window)
plot(daysSince1970RelativeToNow, "daysSince1970RelativeToNow", display = display.data_window)

plot(time_tradingday, "time_tradingday", display = display.data_window)
plot(daysSince1970RelativeToBar, "daysSince1970RelativeToBar", display = display.data_window)
```

Screenshot:
[image]